# Hbase too many items queued

Tags: java, hbase

I use the async client of hbase in java. I execute the get method (`CompletableFuture<Result> get(Get get);`) about 10000 times in a loop. Then I got the message:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CallQueueTooBigException: Call queue is full on ip-10-161-3-55.us-west-2.compute.internal,16020,1678360345005, too many items queued ?
 sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor101.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException.instantiateException(RemoteWithExtrasException.java:99)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteWithExtrasException.java:89)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionUtils.translateException(ConnectionUtils.java:317)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncRpcRetryingCaller.onError(AsyncRpcRetryingCaller.java:159)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncSingleRequestRpcRetryingCaller.lambda$call$4(AsyncSingleRequestRpcRetryingCaller.java:84)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FutureUtils.lambda$addListener$0(FutureUtils.java:68)
 java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
 java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
 java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
 java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RawAsyncTableImpl$1.run(RawAsyncTableImpl.java:182)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.com.google.protobuf.RpcUtil$1.run(RpcUtil.java:79)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.com.google.protobuf.RpcUtil$1.run(RpcUtil.java:70)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.onCallFinished(AbstractRpcClient.java:385)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.access$100(AbstractRpcClient.java:89)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:414)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:410)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.callComplete(Call.java:118)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.setException(Call.java:133)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcDuplexHandler.readResponse(NettyRpcDuplexHandler.java:162)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcDuplexHandler.channelRead(NettyRpcDuplexHandler.java:192)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:311)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:432)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException: Call queue is full on ip-10-161-3-55.us-west-2.compute.internal,16020,1678360345005, too many items queued ?
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.onCallFinished(AbstractRpcClient.java:380)
```

It seems I've sent too many requests to the HBase server. The `hbase.regionserver.handler.count` is 100. Increasing the handler count may help but I think it can't solve this problem completely when there are more requests.

What is the real reason for this exception?

Are there any configurations to control the concurrent of the request or anything that can help?